# How can I merge the subsets of elements in an array that share the same key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mongodb, algorithm

I'm developing a chat system in which all messages are stored in a Mongodb database with the following schema:

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    to: String,
    from: String,
    threadTopic: String,
    messages: [
        {
            content: String,
            date: Date,
        }
    ]

})
```

In this chat system there are "threads" or topics which have a subset of messages. For example, two people could have a conversation on one thread, and those same two people could also have a conversation on a different thread, so I am trying to filter the database output so that it includes all the messages separated by thread.

I am using the following algorithm in order to accomplish this:

```
var finalResult = [];

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < response.length; j++) {

    //Check if there is a match between 2 threadTopics so they can be sonsolidated:
    if (response[i].threadTopic === response[j].threadTopic) {   

      //Extract received messages, i.e. messages sent to the recipient (user)
      const rxMsgs = (response[i].to == "Recipient") ? response[i].messages : response[j].messages

      //Extract messages that the recipient (user) sent
      const txMsgs = (response[i].from = "Recipient") ? response[i].messages : response[j].messages


      const element = {
                        threadName: response[i].threadTopic,
                        msgs: rxMsgs.concat(txMsgs)
                      }

        //append to final consolidated output
        finalOutput = finalOutput.concat(element);
      }
   }
}
```

In essence, this algorithm takes in an array response containing different threads that appear twice in the array (each time with the from:/to: reversed, i.e.: send or receive), and consolidates all the [messages] arrays belonging to each thread. Is there any way to improve this algorithm so that it performs better than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current code gives you the output you want - you can improve the runtime by grouping by `threadTopic` first, but it'll still have quadratic complexity in the worst case (if all response items have the same `threadTopic`). The below approach is much better if multiple items having the same `threadTopic` is unlikely - closer to `O(n)`.

```
const responsesByTopic = {};
for (const oneResponse of response) {
    responsesByTopic[oneResponse.threadTopic] ??= [];
    responsesByTopic[oneResponse.threadTopic].push(oneResponse);
}
const output = [];
for (const [threadName, responses] of Object.entries(responsesByTopic)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < responses.length; j++) {
            const rxMsgs = response[response[i].to === "Recipient" ? i : j].messages;
            const txMsgs = response[response[i].from === "Recipient" ? i : j].messages;
            output.push({
                threadName,
                msgs: rxMsgs.concat(txMsgs)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

(Fundamentally, since for each thread, you're mapping each response to each other response, you can't get past `O(n ^ 2)` there)